# Redundant escape character in Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying out the following code and it's printing false.
I was expected that this would print true.
In addition , the Pattern.Compile() statemenet , gives a warning 'redundant escape character'.
Can someone please help me as to why this is not returning true and why do I see a warning.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "\\n";
    System.out.println(s);

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\n");
    Matcher mm = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(mm.matches());
}
```

Comment: \\n != \\\n - you are comparing the letter 'n' to newline '\n'

Answer (score 8):

The `s="\\n"` means you assign a backslash and `n` to the variable `s`, and it contains a *sequence of two chars*, `\` and `n`.

The `Pattern.compile("\\\n")` means you define a regex pattern `\<LF>` (a backslash and a newline, line feed, char) that *matches a newline (LF) char*, because escaped non-word non-special chars match themselves. `\,` matches a `,`, `\;` matches a `;`.  Thus, this pattern won't match the string in variable `s`.

The redundant escape warning is thrown because `\<LF>` matches the same newline char that can be matched with mere `<LF>`.

More examples:

| Regex | Regex string literal | Matching text | Matching string literal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `<LF>` | `"\n"` | `<LF>` | `"\n"` |
| `\n` | `"\\n"` | `<LF>` | `"\n"` |
| `\\n` | `"\\\\n"` | `\n` | `"\\n"` |

Comment: \\n in means \ and n characters. Also \\\n in pattern should mean : \\n , which means it should match \ and n.

Comment: To match a string that has a backslash and then `n`, you need `String pattern = "\\\\n"`. To match a backslash, you need 4 backslashes in the string literal representing 2 backslashes in the string passed to the regex engine.

Answer (score 3):

Because `"\\n"` evaulates to backslash `\\` and the letter `n` while `"\\\n"` evaluates to a backslash `\\` and then a newline `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Backslashes within string literals in Java source code are interpreted as required by The Java™ Language Specification as either Unicode escapes (section 3.3) or other character escapes (section 3.10.6) It is therefore necessary to double backslashes in string literals that represent regular expressions to protect them from interpretation by the Java bytecode compiler. The string literal "\b", for example, matches a single backspace character when interpreted as a regular expression, while "`\\b`" matches a word boundary.

Refer : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Your source s has two characters, `'\'` and `'n'`, if you meant it would be `\` followed by a line break then it should be `"\\\n"`

Pattern has two characters '\' and '\n' (line break) and \ the escape characher is not needed, hence warning. If you meant \ followed by line break it should be `"\\\\\n"` (twice \ to escape it for regex and then \n).

```
    String s = "\\\n";
    System.out.println(s);

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\\n");

    Matcher mm = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(mm.matches());
```