# Regular expression does not match newline when escaped with backslash

Tags: java, regex, backslash, html-escape-characters

String s will be comprised of two characters: `\` and `n`
Pattern will be evaluated as: `\\n`; in this the first backslash will escape the second and then the character `n` will be present.
So the code snippet should evaluate to true; but instead it's printing false.

What could be the reason?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s="\\n";
    System.out.println(s);

    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\\n");

    Matcher mm=p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(mm.matches());
}
```

Comment: You have already asked the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953460/redundant-escape-character-in-pattern and got answers. If answers are not clear or you wish to improve the question, why not edit original question or comment on it, instead of duplicating with new one.